# Can't show simple ReceiptCard with BotFramework 4

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I can see ReceiptCard content in web chat and Telegram.
But in Skype I can see only the icon.

How can I fix this?

```
    var receiptCard = GetReceiptCard(basketDetails);
    var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(receiptCard);

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity);

    private static Attachment GetReceiptCard(BasketDetails basketDetails)
    {
        var receiptCard = new ReceiptCard
        {
            Title = "Some list",
            Items = basketDetails.Products.Select(r => new ReceiptItem(r.Name, quantity: "1")).ToList(),
            Facts = new List<Fact>(),
            Total = string.Empty,
        };

        return receiptCard.ToAttachment();
    }
```

Comment: I just tested receipt cards in both Skype and Telegram, and they work. Please show the code you're using to generate your receipt card. Did you get it from the samples repo?

Comment: It is partly from the samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Card behavior is channel-specific by nature, so you always need to make sure you test each card in each channel you plan on targeting. And if you want to be safe, make sure you provide non-null values for card properties, especially list types.

It turns out Skype won't accept your card if the total is empty, and Telegram will encounter an error if the items or facts are null. So you can fix your card for both channels like this:

```
var receiptCard = new ReceiptCard
{
    Title = "Some list",
    Items = basketDetails.Products.Select(r => new ReceiptItem(r.Name, quantity: "1")).ToList(),
    Facts = new List<Fact>(),
    Total = "Unknown",
};
```

Comment: Thank you.
It is fixed Telegram channel, but with Skype problem still exist

Comment: I can see in your modified question that your total is still empty. You have to provide a total.

Comment: Thank you again.
I thought empty string is acceptable value.